# Size_hint is doing weird things and being very inconsistent

Tags: python, kivy

I've created 4 "indicator buttons" and I've given all of them the same size_hint values, but they don't have the same size when I launch the program. Additionally I've created "validate buttons" (which also share the same size_hint values) and again, when I launch the program, they don't have the same size.
Did I miss something? How exactly does size_hint work? (the indicator buttons are the large squares on the top right corner of the picture)

---

```
 #indicators for the 1st row of buttons
    Button:
        id: i11
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0.7}
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.065
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: root.colori11

    Button:
        id: i12
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.18, "y": 0.7}
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.065
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: root.colori12

    Button:
        id: i13
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.16, "y": 0.7}
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.065
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: root.colori13

    Button:
        id: i14
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.14, "y": 0.7}
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.065
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: root.colori14

#validate button
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.66, "y": 0.725}
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.065
        text: "V"
        on_release:
            root.btn_action_v2()
```

---

[picture of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk37A.png)

Comment: On one of the Buttons you use `size_hint`, but on the others you use `size`.

Comment: ah yeah sorry i was switching between size and size_hint to see if it would change anything, i've corrected my mistake. But still, it seems that at very low values (e.g. 0.01) my buttons behave very strangely (like, these line cutting through my buttons)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I've done several Kivy layouts and have never once used **pos_hint** so my suggestion is to comment those away and see what result you get.

size_hint is a relative and so I have always used integers as I find those a bit easier to work with.  Furthermore you have the option to use **size_hint_x** or **size_hint_y** individually